# Gods are real, why is there still corruption within the Church then?

Tags: science-based, politics, religion

Gods and religious organizations are a frequent part of "typical" fantasy, but there is a problem with them:

1. Gods grant miracles to their followers on a fairly constant basis.
2. I want to have a corrupt Church.

Okay, what do I mean by corruption?

### Heavenly Court and Gods

Storywise, there are multiple "good" gods. They have semi-independent religions but are ultimately controlled by the governing body, **G**ood **G**ods **U**ndivided. Gods differ in power can't directly aid mortals, but are allowed to lend them their own power within certain bounds. The power they give is based on that god's nature. It's not as much of a hard rule, but they're better and more efficient at what they're specialized for.

Every god is a member and servant of the Heavenly Court, led by Mephistopheles (not OP, a different one), The Secretary Emperor. The Secretary Emperor can't propose legislation but has veto rights, and the other gods can propose, reject, and pass legislation, but only if Meph agrees.

The Heavenly Court is also a court, for when mortals with divine allowances are doing questionable stuff. Meph's the judge and the executioner, the rest of the gods are the jury.

### Living Saints

In the mortal realm, people who lead lifestyles that suit a particular god can call upon their miracles a given number of times.

The number and types of miracles at one's disposal is determined by their rank. Living saints sit at the top, being one of a god's favourites. In fact, being a living saint means you instantly become a noble with your own troops to command and some new obligations to protect your given land.

**C**rusader **G**od and **M**edicare **G**oddess are two prominent figures. CG is the most powerful god and his living saints are the most numerous and are pretty much all knights (regardless of origin, for any peasant hero out there).

There is also the Church's governing body, the members of which can call on any miracle, but theirs are usually somewhat weaker. In order for one to become a member, one has to be elected by representatives of other branches (excluding their own).

---

Did you get all that? Well, let's jump into what problems is it supposed to have:

**CG's little paladins**, while having a code to abide by, **are** oftentimes **transparently racists** towards demi-humans and dragons **and** just **a wee bit aggressive**. They won't jump (immediately) at a lizardman or a dragon but would have no issue calling them racial slurs.

**The governing body is** so elitist they make Arch, Gentoo, and **Apple users** look patient and warm-hearted.

The Church also has gryphons, catbirds with human intelligence and the ability to speak. While in the holy text itself, it's stated that gryphons are divine in origins and serve the greater good, it's interpreted as:

***Gryphons are good because they serve the Church**. In fact, those gryphons that said nay to their obligations and wanted to stay out of the War in Heavens were cursed by the gods to bear the marks of The Serpent, becoming the first dragons.*

Which isn't really true. Dragons were neutral, but you can't bash someone for not sacrificing their lives for you in a conflict you've started.

So, gryphons are good because they loyally serve their riders and dragons that end up as a <s>slave</s> steed of a living saint are atoners. I mean, they needed to justify any dragon riders that might come.

Should a gryphon become a living saint, she would definitely be opposed and constantly assigned to tasks perceived of little importance and would be granted just enough funding to make ends meet. I mean, gryphons are treated well, "it's just that a gryphon is a gods' gift to me for all the collected good-boi points". You get where I'm going with it.

**And the gods can't do much about it. Why? What institutional problems could explain it?**

**Remember, the gods are supposed to** be good, they **understand that racism** and things like spreading misinformation that lizardmen are poisonous (they're mildly venomous, BIG difference) are **not okay**.

**Suppose that the social structure is medieval and that miracles keep diseases in check and allow for the faster propagation of information.**

Comment: Back in elementary, I had a history book where the bold text was a TL;DR of the chapter it was in. I'm still trying to emulate it.

Comment: How and why are the gods invested in the acts of non-gods? Are the gods using mortals for a war by proxy or as entertainment? Knowing their motivation (or some approximation thereof) could help understand why they give some mortals power without policing them too closely. In general, as long as things move in the "right" direction (over billions of eons), the precise details might mot matter so much to (nigh?) immortal beings.

Comment: "led by Mephistopheles (not OP, a different one)" suuuurrreeeee its not

Comment: Well, God **is** real (as far as the churches are concerned), and yet all churches fell into corruption from time to time. I don't get how this is different from the real world. (And I don't get the joke about the difference between venom and poison.) (The universal justification is that God moves in mysterious ways. The creature cannot comprehend the creator. There is a Great Plan, but it is not for mortals to understand it. Etc.)

Comment: I'd vote to reopen if you offered some criteria by which the question could be answered in a non-opinionated way. Also, lizardmen notwithstanding, God ìs real and, as we saw in the other question, there is also corruption in the Church -- so what makes your query fit for the WB and not Christianity forum?

Comment: This just sounds too much like gaming. Most GMs I've run with for DnD had a church and gods that were much like this.

Comment: @NomadMaker Well, yes, that's the purpose of the question. I mean, not an actual game setting but one based on them that turns some tropes on their heads while leaving others intact.

Answer (score 5):

The gods see a bigger picture.

You’ve got to remember that Gods, by their nature, see more than mere mortals and plan both over the longer term and with much more intricacy. Their goals, while unquestionably good, might not seem so honourable on the small scale.

Consider the following: the Gods know an Ancient Evil is going to wipe out the Church in one kingdom They also know that, with the best will in the world, the pious, righteous souls they really *want* working for them aren’t up to saving the kingdom. They can’t enlist most of the hardcore mercenaries (since they’re only in it for the cash) so they arrange things so the local crime bosses can take over the church, dole out some miracles, engage in some light corruption and then (after a couple of generations once the Ancient Evil has been dropped in the nearest harbour wearing a chicken wire vest and concrete overshoes because the local mob bosses had Holy Wrath on their side) be defeated from within by a grassroots movement of True Believers that wouldn’t have *existed* if it weren’t for the corruption.

The gods simultaneously defeat the big bad, weed out corrupt criminals and temper the Faithful in the area into a clergy hardened against Evil. All it cost was a couple of generations of corruption. What’s that to a deity?

Now generalise that out to a continent. Make it more intricate and deep. Allowing a Saint to be corrupted now might save ten thousand souls in the future, and one traitorous disciple could set up a prophet for their greatest miracle yet. If your gods are wary they will have plans nestled in plans nestled in plans, playing with the lives of the faithful (and unfaithful) in a never ending series of [Xanatos’ Gambits](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/XanatosGambit). To the mere mortal this appears to make the church corrupt and capricious, but any higher planar being will immediately see how the long term plan is to the benefit of all.

After all: Gods work in mysterious ways.

Answer (score 2):

This was a plot point for Green Lanterns many times. They are granted powers to become the Galaxy's police by a power greater and more noble than them (The Guardians). Sometimes a Green Lantern will be an absolute ************ (Guy Gardner), sometimes just an average idiot (Hal Jordan at times). And the Guardians are ok with thay, because they know it's as good as they can get while still having free will among their troops. They tried using robots before and it turned out badly for them.

Green Lantern rings choose their Lanterns by picking the most courageous and honorable person in their sector. Sometimes a sector only has thieves and liars, so a thief and a liar it is.

---

Not even the best human is incorruptible. Either the good gods lower their standards and accept that or they will have no servants.

Answer (score 1):

Because the gods know that freedom is good.

They could control non-gods to such an extent that they will all be good, but it would require a degree of control that would make that of Big Brother in *1984* look like a liberatarian paradise.

Answer (score 1):

#### The Church is a Political Organization, Not a Faith One

Churches are created to provide services to the communities : blessing crops and homes, performing marriages and burials, tending to the sick, feeding the poor.

Church hierarchies organize village efforts at a higher level - county, province, kingdom. They allow resources and people to be pooled and focused wherever the need is most dire.

Top-level Church hierarchies liaise with the king. They perform functions such as advice, lobbying, and information. The Church may be assigned duties from the kingdom such as maintenance of monuments, managing the king’s charitable projects, organizing festivals, keeping records of births and deaths and the lines of the noble families.

The Top-level Church may also liaise with the Churches of the other deities. They may set members to sit at interfaith councils. This may bring about even more duties - such as management of missionaries in foreign kingdoms, a religious court to solve disputes between monarchs, a court to resolve disputes between faiths.

None of these activities require faith.

#### The Gods Use Those Who Listen

Your living saints likely have low, or no, standing within the Church. They do what their god tells them to do, say what their god tells them to say, and otherwise properly conduct themselves as someone the deity can trust as a “go to” person.

While the Church by definition has split loyalties to the communities, kingdoms, and inter-faith organizations it serves, the living saint is expected to have no such split devotion.

The god may still be involved with the Church. But there are times and places where the Church will be in poor agreement with their deity.

Answer (score 1):

## Why give people free will?

Why even have people at all?  If you have to have people, why give them free will in the first place?  And if you have to have people, and they have to have free will, why build into them the desire to do wrong, anyway?

Philosophers have been wrestling with these questions for a *very* long time.  Many fantasy novels just kind of gloss over these issues.  I submit that the answer to your question lies in answering them.

One possible answer is that the whole point of having people is they have free will.  But free will would be meaningless if people were built to only desire to do what the gods wanted them to do anyway.  So they *have* to have the desire to do ill, and the freedom to exercise it, otherwise why bother?  Therefore the gods do not rule the mortal realm; after all, if they really wanted to, they could. Clearly they don't.

Another possible answer is that the cosmos - the gods, the heavens, the earth, and all the people in it - are flawed in some way.  That ultimately explains both human foibles and the gods' inability to lead by example.

Find this world's answers to these questions, and then you will know why the answer is forty two.

Answer (score 0):

## A few simple possible reasons.

**First of all, there is the "free will" defense.** The gods wanted all the races to be able to choose their own choices. They still make their presence known, sure, but people themselves are able to do their own thing.

**Second possibility: They can't, for some odd reason.** Perhaps there is a barrier or something that only allows them to send portions of their power(miracles) through, and not nearly enough to, let's say, smite anyone.

**Third possibility: The gods have some huge plan.** As Joe Bloggs stated, they are gods. They plan much more intricately and over long term than mere mortals. They are willing to sacrifice a whole generation of corrupt people and a few innocents in favor of completing their plan. While their goals are good, they are less than honorable in getting their way. An entire sequence of [Xanatos Gambits](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/XanatosGambit).

**Finally, there is the possibility that they just don't care.** They are gods. Who cares if a few thousand mortals are treated badly? To them, as long as the universal balance is maintained, all is well.